# How to execute tool window shorcuts while in the intellij terminal?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Sometimes I want to quickly maximize the terminal window but the shortcut doesn't work. I think it probably has to do with the cursor being inside the terminal itself when the command is run because the command works fine with the other tool windows. The command on my mac should be `option`+`shift`+`'`.

Comment: Please try to disable "Override IDE shortcuts" in "Preferences | Tools | Terminal"

Comment: That did it, thank you!